# PHP - How to assign new name attribute in case of illegal name is given when object is created?

Tags: php, class, oop, object, assign

I'm learning how to OOP and I'd like to know how to assign new name attribute for a newly created object, for example "NoName", when the given name is illegal (in this case shorter than 2 words or longer than 50 words). Currently, when I create a new object it still displays the name "E", while it should display "NoName". Is there something wrong with my if else statement?

Here's the class:

```
<?php 
class Person {

private $name;

public function __construct($name){
$this->name=$name;
}

public function setName($name){
    if((strlen($name)>=2) && (strlen($name)<=50)){
    $this->name=$name;
    $accepted = true;
    }else{
    $accepted = false;
    $this->name="NoName";
    }
    return $accepted;
}

public function __toString() {
    $temp = "name of the person is " . $this->name;
    return $temp;       
    }   
}
?>
```

And here is where I create the objects:

```
 $p1 = new Person("Kenneth");
 echo("<p>" . $p1 ."</p>");

 $p2 = new Person("E");
 echo("<p> Illegal name when created: " . $p2 ."</p>");
```

Comment: You never use setName in your constructor. I guess that's what you want to do ?

Comment: Well you never call the setname method?

Comment: In your constructor you could, instead of `$this->name=$name;` do `$this->setName($name);` though your `$accepted` boolean appears unused

Comment: @user574632 You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar ok have done

Comment: And by the way, `strlen` counts characters, not words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way is to throw an exception:

```
class Person {

    private $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->setName($name);
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        if (strlen($name) < 2 || strlen($name) > 50) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Name is too short or too long');
        }
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}
```

- it is "physically" impossible to set a name which does not meet your criteria, because otherwise an exception is thrown
- the constructor uses the `setName` method to enforce this as well
- bottom line: it is impossible* to have an instance of the `Person` class with an invalid name

<sub>* barring actual runtime language hacks</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You never call the setName method
In your constructor you could, instead of

```
$this->name=$name;
```

do

```
$this->setName($name);
```

though your `$accepted` boolean appears unused

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
class Person {

    private $name;

    public function __construct($name){
        $this->setName($name);
    }

    public function setName($name){
        if(preg_match('/.{2,50}/',$name) != 1){
            throw new DomainException("Invalid 'name' format.");
        }
        $this->name=$name;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return "name of the person is " . $this->name;       
    }   
}


function CreatePersonHelper($name) {
    try{
        return new Person($name);
        echo("<p>" . $p1 ."</p>");
    } catch (DomainExcetion $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 'Something went wrong';
    }
}

$names = array('Kenneth','e');
foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo CreatePersonHelper($name);
}
```